# Cassandra write timeout exception when increasing number of nodes in cluster

Tags: cassandra

we have a Cassandra cluster consisting 1 to 5 nodes. Replication factor is 3. Write consistency is ONE.

We have a bunch of column families. For each CF, we burst insert hundreds of thoudsands of units of data into the cluster. Now, we get WriteTimeoutException: "1 replica has to respond to the write, but 0 did"

1. When cluster consists of more than one nodes.
2. With some of the CFs.

The structure of the CFs are nothing special. For example, this CF always gives the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE data_field_value_history (
  df BIGINT,
  caid TEXT,
  cre TIMESTAMP,
  user BIGINT,
  rs INT,
  val TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY ((df, caid), cre)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (cre DESC);
```

But this CF never gives problem:

```
CREATE TABLE data_field_value (
    shop INT,
    wh INT,
  df BIGINT,
  caid TEXT,
  mod TIMESTAMP,
  val TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY ((shop, wh), df, caid)
);
```

I cannot tell what is the special difference between these two that makes up the problem?

Thanks a lot for any suggestion!

Comment: Can you please show your keyspace definition?

Comment: Keyspace definition: CREATE KEYSPACE cp_business
    WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3};

Comment: What do you mean by "consisting 1 to 5 nodes"? Does this change?

Comment: On writes a timeout is not a failure. See the Datastax article, [When a timeout is not a failure](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-cassandra-deals-with-replica-failure). The node stores the writes as hints until availability has returned.

Comment: Zerd1984: Firstly we have 1 node in cluster, everything perfect. We increased to 3 nodes, performance worsened. Increased to 5 nodes, even much more worse!
Nathan: Yes it is not a failure, problem is our cluster is not under stress! CPU load is only approx. 1%. We just dont get it!